# Google Sheets: IF function reading text and returning percentage AND if another cell in a same row is empty then it returns no inpuct

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to achieve the goal below, and it partially works, however, when cell A2 is empty, then I'm getting 0% (preferably I would like to get no input). Any idea how to divide the formula?

The formula I'm currently using that works but not perfectly:
`=IF(AND(A2<>"",B2="",C2="",D2="",E2="",F2=""),"100%","0%")`

**Goal:**

1. If cells from B2 to F2 are empty, then 100%
2. If one of the cells is not empty, then 0%
3. If cell A is empty, then "" (the cell should be empty without any % symbol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work by adding another check. If one of the cells within `B2:F2` are not empty, then it checks if A2 is empty. If it is, it returns a blank value. If it is not, it returns 0%.

`=IF(ISBLANK(A2), "", if(AND(B2="",C2="",D2="",E2="",F2=""),"100%", "0%"))`

Comment: Hi and thanks but the formula works partially: it correctly returns 100% when the cells from B2 to F2 are empty but it incorrectly returns empty cell when some of the cells are not empty (it should be 0% instead) and it incorrectly returns 100% when A2 is empty (it should be empty cell)

Comment: It seems I had the order of things mixed up a bit. I edited my answer with what should be the correct formula. Let me know if you have any other issues with it

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=IF(A2="",,IF((B2="")*(C2="")*(D2="")*(E2="")*(F2=""), "100%", "0%"))
```